# LINQ: Inner join 2 table + outer join 1 table

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 2 inner joins (3 tables) but I don't know and I find it hard to implement my research about outer join in LINQ. How do I change the last inner join to outer join, such that column will still join even if the column (Role) is null?

Here's an existing SQL version of this which I want to convert to LINQ:

```
SELECT dbo.EmployeeAccess.id, dbo.EmployeeAccess.EmpNo, dbo.EmployeeAccess.RoleID, dbo.EmployeeAccess.Active, dbo.EmployeeAccessLevel.Role, 
                  dbo.View_HCM.LNameByFName

FROM  dbo.EmployeeAccess LEFT OUTER JOIN
      dbo.EmployeeAccessLevel ON dbo.EmployeeAccess.RoleID = dbo.EmployeeAccessLevel.id INNER JOIN
      dbo.View_HCM ON dbo.EmployeeAccess.EmpNo = dbo.View_HCM.EmpNo
```

LINQ I now have with 2 inner joins:

```
    (from ea in context.EmployeeAccesses
                    join vh in context.View_HCM on (Int16)ea.EmpNo equals vh.EmpNo
                    join rl in context.EmployeeAccessLevels on ea.RoleID equals rl.id 
                    select new EmployeeWithEmail{

                        EmpNum = ea.EmpNo ?? 0,
                        EmailAddress = vh.EmailAddress,                          
                        LNameByFname = vh.LNameByFName,                                  
                        Active2 = ea.Active ?? false

                    }).ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq's outer join syntax uses 2 parts.  First an `into` then `DefaultIfEmpty`

In your case, an outer join might look like this:

```
(from ea in context.EmployeeAccesses
join vh in context.View_HCM on (Int16)ea.EmpNo equals vh.EmpNo
join rl in context.EmployeeAccessLevels on ea.RoleID equals rl.id into outer_join
from subjoin in outer_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new EmployeeWithEmail{

    EmpNum = ea.EmpNo ?? 0,
    EmailAddress = vh.EmailAddress,                          
    LNameByFname = vh.LNameByFName,                                  
    Active2 = ea.Active ?? false

}).ToList();
```

There are [many tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin) on how to create the outer join in LINQ.

Comment: Your code works and with that I can better understand this topic. Thanks! In so many of the articles I've searched, your link was way more understandable and one I wish I could've found earlier.